# How to read from keyboard a complete random text, filter and cast

Tags: c++, casting, cin

I`m developing a Tic Tac Toe game for school, but it is getting difficult develop a nice way to read a play from keyboard, in a practical and nice formated way.

This is what I did:

```
Human::play() const
{ 
  int pos           
  std::cout << endl << Name << ", please, insert the desirable move:";
                     //^^this is a class atribute
  std::string keyboard;
  std::stringstream ss;

  std::getline(std::cin, keyboard);

  ss << keyboard[0];
  ss >> pos;

  return (pos);
}//end of Human class method *play*
```

This function will be called and I will verify if the player move was acceptable, thus, see if it is between *0 and 8*. Also, I would like to check if there was an entry of *"r"* or *"q"*, as it will mean that the player wants to come back one turn or quit the game.

To check if the player had enter this instructions, I do this i.e:

```
int playermove = player1.play()
if (playermove == 'q')
    ...
```

I am having troubles because from what was shown above, **pos** is returned 0 when a character is entered. But, I don't see any practical solutions.

Could you please suggest me alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for `r` and `q` and on false just subtract -48 (because of ASCII table).

Check this out:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char tmp;
    cin >> tmp;
    if(tmp == 'q') {
        cout << tmp;
        return 0;
    } else {
        int smth = tmp;
        cout << smth - 48;
        return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This will catch `q` and numbers. You can then check if (smth - 48) is in range 0-9 by checking (> -48 && < -39).